# Changing the class of an element with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I am generating some div elements here :

```
 $.each(obj.teams, function(d, t) {
              count+=1;
              team = "";
              replay_teams+= '<div class="rgtside" id="team'+count+'">';
              ...
```

As we can see on this picture, my divs are generated as intended with good ids :

[image]

Also, I have some radiobuttons (cb..), and I gave it a change function where I am trying to change the class of my div according to the selected radiobutton.

```
 //loop over some stuffs to generate the radio...
 $("#cb"+id) // select the radio by its id
    .change(function(){ // bind a function to the change event
        if( $(this).is(":checked") ){ // check if the radio is checked
        selectedWinner = $(this).val(); // retrieve the value
        console.log("new value : "+selectedWinner)
        var i;
        for (i = 1; i < array.length+1; i++) { 
          $("#team"+i).attr('class','rgtside'); //reset all div with the normal class
        }
        $("#team"+selectedWinner).attr('class','rgtside win'); //assign the good class to the winner   
    }
 });
```

My function appears to work as I get a message in my console everytimes I change the selected value of my radiobuttons.

It seems like this line of code is not working :
`$("#team"+selectedWinner).attr('class','rgtside win');` 
as I can't replace the **rgtside** class with **rgtside win**...

It looks like it cannot find my div element but the id is correct?

Comment: Please post the entire code that can replicate the issue.

Comment: sorry the code was way too hard to summarize in few lines of codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)**, **[`removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)**, and **[`toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)** methods instead of `attr()`. BTW, there's no need to include `.rgtside` class if it's always on each div because those jQuery methods only add/remove the classes specified they do not overwrite the `class` attribute like `className` property does.

### Demo

```js
$(':radio').change(function() {
  var selectedWinner = $(this).val();
  $('.rgtside').removeClass('win');
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $("#team" + selectedWinner).addClass('win');
  } else {
    $("#team" + selectedWinner).removeClass('win');
  }
});

//OR

/*
$(':radio').on('click', function() {
  var selectedWinner = $(this).val();
  $('.rgtside').removeClass('win');
  $('#team'+selectedWinner).toggleClass('win');
});
*/
```

```css
.win {
  outline: 5px solid red
}
```

```html
<input type='radio' name='rad' value='0'> 0
<input type='radio' name='rad' value='1'> 1
<input type='radio' name='rad' value='2'> 2

<div id='team0' class='rgtside'>team 0</div>
<div id='team1' class='rgtside'>team 1</div>
<div id='team2' class='rgtside'>team 2</div>





<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No problem, happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, see if helps:

```
$("#td_id").toggleClass('rgtside win');
```